# laptop screen won't show up

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, external-monitor

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, and for some reason I can't use the laptop screen WITHOUT an external monitor; it functions fine as the only monitor in windows 8, and it functions fine as the primary monitory in a dual monitor setup in ubuntu...it just doesn't work as the ONLY monitor in ubuntu. Any ideas?

Here is the laptop: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834215665

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try `arandr` utility.
Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Then launch it. You will be able to configure your monitors with graphical utility.